# Jira issues that are in an epic with certain label

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to write a Jira JQL filter that combines parentEpic with a label or a filter.
The below JQL works:

```
project=TML AND parentEpic in (TML-2731, TML-3053)
```

But then I need to know the IDs of the epics, and these only live for few weeks.
Labels live much longer, and I can easily search for epics with a label:

```
project=TML AND issuetype=Epic AND labels in (IndEquip, IndAuto)
```

But now I would like to use the returned list of epics as input to the parentEpic function, but this does not work:

```
project=TML AND parentEpic in (labels in (IndEquip, IndAuto))
```

Are such nested queries in general not possible? Is there any extension that makes it possible?

Comment: It's possible with ScriptRunner: `issueFunction in issuesInEpics('labels in (IndEquip, IndAuto)')`

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the comment, it isn't possible with Jira basic Jql capability.

However it is possible with the ScriptRunner App and the Enhanced Jql issuesinEpics

[Example Server version](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/latest/features/jql-functions/included-jql-functions/issue-links#id-.IssueLinksv8.2.0-issuesInEpics)

[Cloud version Enhanced Search](https://scriptrunner-docs.connect.adaptavist.com/jiracloud/enhanced-search.html)